# Distributed Jenkins- Master on Linux and slave on windows- How to configure node specific setting

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

This is background for my question.

I have setup distributed Jenkins where the master is running in RHEL linux box and slave is running on a windows box. I did not have any problem in registering the slave node to the master.

In master Jenkins, under manage Jenkins page, I have provided the maven path detail corresponds to master (/opt/maven3).

Now I have create maven2/3 job and assigned the job exclusively on slave node. But when slave is running the maven job on windows, it is taking the maven path installed the master (/opt/maven3), since this path is not valid in windows, throws up an error.

I tried to override the value with pre-build steps, setting M2_HOME and PATH environment entries. but in vein.

So in simple term, How do I configure the node specific settings in Jenkins?

Mean I want to specify in Node 1- Maven path is XXX/maven3 and in node-2 maven path is yyy/zzz/maven3.

Answer (score 1):

Override the settings as follows:
**System Management**  ->  **Node Management** -> your slave setting -> **Node Properties** -> check the *Tools Locations* -> **Add** , then set the slave maven option,*alias* select "maven",*directory* write with the slave maven directory.
you can try it.